# How to add a class to a certain element containing an id?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my dropdown list,

```
<li class=dropdown>
    <a class=dropdown-toggle data-toggle=dropdown  href=# id='ent_management'>Ent Management <span class=caret></span></a>
    <ul class=dropdown-menu>
        <li><a href='ent_intern.php'>Student Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href='ent_arrangement_data.php'>Student management</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

When I click either Student Resume or Student management, the page will redirect to the corresponding page, which will refresh the page. 
I'd like to add an **active** class to **Ent Management** when the page is redirected. And this is how I did it:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#ent_management').addClass('active');
</script>
<style>
    .active{
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

It doesn't work actually. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your script is included in the head section, it will always run when the page loads, not just a refresh.

Comment: Yes, I have included the script in the head section, but it's still not working. ;(

Comment: You must include it in 'ent_intern.php' and 'ent_arrangement_data.php', not just the main page, if you want it to run after redirecting.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){  here your code to add class to specific element  });

Comment: @Poul Bak Yes, that's what I did, I added the script in both the php files.

Comment: @DejavuGuy I tried this: <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#ent_management").addClass('active');
 });
</script> Still doens't work well.

Comment: did you try like this...

not with single quote .addClass('active')
with double quote .addClass("active")

Comment: @DejavuGuy Yes, but it seems that it's not due to the double quote. But still thank you for answering ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code. After code change please clear your browser cache then refresh the page. Hope this will work for you.

```
window.onload = function(){
  $("#ent_management").addClass("active");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually violating DOM rules. Do it this way:

```html
<style>
    .active{
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<li class=dropdown>
    <a class=dropdown-toggle data-toggle=dropdown  href=# id='ent_management'>Ent Management <span class=caret></span></a>
    <ul class=dropdown-menu>
        <li><a href='ent_intern.php'>Student Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href='ent_arrangement_data.php'>Student management</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#ent_management').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in my browser it seems to be still the same. ;(